# Understanding a Deadlock in Go

Tags: go, deadlock

I have the following excerpt from an example given in a programming course, and I am not sure why a deadlock is occurring.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    Count      int = 0
    nFunctions int = 2
)

var sema = make(chan int)

func increment(ch chan int, nSteps int) {
    for i := 0; i < nSteps; i++ {
        <- sema  
        cnt := Count
        Count = cnt + 1
        ch <- 1
        sema <- 1
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    sema <- 1
    go increment(ch, 1000)
    go increment(ch, 1000)

    for i := 0; i < nFunctions*1000; i++ {
        <-ch
    }

    fmt.Printf("Count = %d\n", Count)
}
```

Strangely, the deadlock does not occur when I change the statement, in the main, from `sema <- 1` to

```
go func () {
sema <- 1
}()
```

Any explanations for this much appreciated. The error message is :
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channels block both the sender and the receiver. If you send something, you are blocked until it is received. You could reduce your code even further, all you need is a channel and then write to that channel. Note that you could also use a [buffered channel](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3), which allows writes up to the buffer length without blocking. If the buffer is full however, it does still block.